Facing issues with the Join Query in the Go Project using MySQL Database
I am creating a go project and facing an issue with the join query.
I am not getting the columns of the joined tables in the project using GORM/GIN. But when I debug that query and use it in the MySQL, I get it perfect results.
Required Models:
type MetaType struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID   uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name string    `gorm:"type:varchar(64);unique"`
}
type MetaData struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID          uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    MetaKey     string    `gorm:"type:varchar(64);unique"`
    MetaValue   string    `gorm:"type:text"`
    Description string    `gorm:"type:text"`
    MetaTypeID  uuid.UUID `gorm:"index"`
    CreatedBy   uuid.UUID `gorm:"index"`
}
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID               uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Username         string    `gorm:"type:varchar(64);unique"`
    FirstName        string    `gorm:"type:varchar(64)"`
    LastName         string    `gorm:"type:varchar(64)"`
    Email            string    `gorm:"type:varchar(128);unique"`
    Password string `gorm:"type:varchar(255)"`
}


Code facing Issue:
//debug above query
    query = query.Debug()
    // Execute query to retrieve Meta Data
    var metaData []models.MetaData
    if err := query.Offset(offset).Limit(pageSize).Select("meta_data.*, meta_types.name as meta_type_name, CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as created_by_name").
        Joins("left join meta_types on meta_data.meta_type_id = meta_types.id").
        Joins("left join users on meta_data.created_by = users.id").
        Find(&metaData).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error retrieving meta data:", err)

        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": "Failed to retrieve meta data",
        })
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("metaData:", metaData)

Result:

Debugged Query:
SELECT meta_data.*, meta_types.name as meta_type_name, CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as created_by_name FROM `meta_data` left join meta_types on meta_data.meta_type_id = meta_types.id left join users on meta_data.created_by = users.id WHERE `meta_data`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 10

Result in MySQL:

If you see in both results, I don't get any error but also there is difference in the results.
In Golang, I am not getting any columns of other tables. (last 2 columns in MySQL result).

You are returning the properties of a metaData object, which obviously does not have any non-metadata properties (columns).

@Shadow ok. So, what would be the solution for this according to you?

I don't know as I only know mysql and not go. I found this question as it was tagged with mysql, but it obviously has nothing to do with it as the question is about the use of go orm.
